# Creating a bleep/beep test application. (Issues with waiting for function to complete)

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I am creating a web application with JS and HTML that will allow users to perform a beep test.

If you are unfamiliar with the test it requires participants to run 15 metres before the beep sounds and then back 15 metres before the beep sounds again, repeating this until they fail to run the 15m before the beep sounds. They start on level 1 which requires them to run 9 lengths, each in less than 6.35s, then level 2 which is 10 lengths in less than 6s each, all the way to level 21.

You read more on in here if you like (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_fitness_test)

I have an array of the different levels (truncated for the sake of simplicity)

```
const levels = [
  {
    level: 1,
    laps: 9,
    lapTime: 6350,
  },
  {
    level: 2,
    laps: 10,
    lapTime: 6000,
  },
  {
    level: 3,
    laps: 11,
    lapTime: 5680,
  },
  {
    level: 4,
    laps: 11,
    lapTime: 5400,
  },
];
```

I then have the following code which loops through the levels, going through each of their laps.

```
function beepTest() {
  // Loop through all the levels
  for (let currentLevel = 0; currentLevel < levels.length; currentLevel++) {
    // Loop through all the laps on the current level
    for (let i = 0; i <= levels[currentLevel].laps; i++) {
      let countdownStartTime = Date.now() + levels[currentLevel].lapTime;
      // This is where the issue is, we need to wait for the countdown to reach 0 before we move to next loop iteration (currently all loops are executed immediately)
      let interval = setInterval(function () {
        let elapsedTime = ((Date.now() - countdownStartTime) / -1000).toFixed(2); // Calulate countdown timer
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = elapsedTime; // Update the displayed countdown timer
        if (elapsedTime <= 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 10); // runs every 10 ms (This code compares the countdown with the current time every 10ms to ensure that the timer is accurate and not shifting)
    }
  }
}
```

This code does not work as it immediately loops to the final level as there is no need for it to wait for the timer to complete before moving to the next loop through. I have tried using promises to fix this but I couldn't get it to work as I am completely new to them and I wasn't sure if they were even the right thing to use in this instance.

clearInterval doesn't seem to do anything either (The if statement it is contained in **does** work as expected however.